# How to make an array with values longer (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, numbers, formula

```
Array = [0, 4, 10, -20, 10, 20, 50]
```

I want this array after an formula that makes it look like this or similar

```
Array = [0, 2, 4, 7, 10, -5, -20, -5, 10, 15, 20, 35, 50]
```

What it does is, it checks the distance between the numbers and then divides the distance by 2, then it adds it to the middle of those values.

Comment: For the next question (although there will definitely be someone that answers it anyway...) - You're supposed to show at least some effort to solve problems on your own. Also your supposed to do [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) before posting a question. SO is not a free code-writing/[homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) service.

Comment: I wasn't sure what to google for. Do you have any advice on how to know what to google for?

Comment: It's a quite specific task, so there might not be something to search for. But you described the rule, which only requires a simple loop and some math. There is no indication that you even tried to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: How do I solve it myself next time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the array (e.g. using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)), pushing values and the intermediate value into a new array as you go:

```js
const arr = [0, 4, 10, -20, 10, 20, 50];

const res = [];
arr.forEach((v, i) => {
  if (i != 0) res.push((v + arr[i - 1]) / 2);
  res.push(v);
});

console.log(res);
```

You could also use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap), creating both entries at once by mapping the array and then flattening the result:

```js
const arr = [0, 4, 10, -20, 10, 20, 50];

const res = arr.flatMap((v, i) => i == 0 ? v : [(v + arr[i - 1]) / 2, v]);

console.log(res);
```

You could also (as suggested by Som in the comments), ignore the array indexing issue when `i == 0` and just slice off the `NaN` value that is generated:

```js
const arr = [0, 4, 10, -20, 10, 20, 50];

const res = arr.flatMap((v, i) => [(v + arr[i - 1]) / 2, v]).slice(1);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: You could get rid of the conditional by doing `v + arr[i+1]` and then strip the last `NaN` value.

Comment: @SomShekharMukherjee indeed, I see you have done that in your edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can map the array into a 2D array and then flatten it.

```js
const arr = [0, 4, 10, -20, 10, 20, 50];

const res = arr
  .map((a, i) => [a, (arr[i + 1] + a) / 2])
  .flat()
  .slice(0, -1);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: This is a good alternative to the conditional in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const array = [0, 4, 10, -20, 10, 20, 50]

const newArray = []

array.forEach((arr, idx) => {
  newArray.push(arr)
  if (idx <= array.length - 2) {
    newArray.push((array[idx + 1] + arr) / 2)
  }
})

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could using [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) for the distance and the current value.

```js
const arr = [0, 4, 10, -20, 10, 20, 50];
let res = [];

arr.forEach((v, i) => res = i > 0 ? res.concat([(v + arr[i - 1]) / 2, v]) : [v]);

console.log(res);
```